# Generator Breaker Placement

Tags: circuit-breaker, generator

I'm trying to add a 30 amp generator inlet box to my panel.  As you can see, I had room in my panel on the top left for a 30 amp breaker.  I was planning to connect my generator inlet box to this but the interlock kits are designed for placement on the right side.  I would have to move a lot of things on the right to make room.  I would prefer to leave it on the left.  If I can fit an interlock switch on the left am I good or is there a reason why these kits are assuming top right placement?

[image]

Comment: FYI that Siemens breaker needs to go. It is not approved for Homeline panels and may damage the bus bars.

Comment: Right side is probably arbitrary.   Making two different ones seems pointless.  Why would you have to move "a lot" of things?  2 things?

Answer (score 5):

Just convenience of design, no need for an extra linkage.   If you can find an approved interlock for the left side, go for it.

But it would be crazy-easy to swap the 30A breaker for the 15-20A breakers opposite.   Even my local "very boutique" hardware store would charge maybe $2 for the required kit: 4 feet of #12 black THHN by-the-foot and two yellow wire nuts.  If you were thinking "it can't be that easy", it is :)

Only hot wires move. The neutrals and grounds can stay put.

FYI you can't cross across the busway between or underneath breakers, but over top or bottom is fine.

If it's the 30A cable that needs moving, then ditto ditto **#10** THHN **red** wire nut.

I'm assuming whoever wired your panel nipped all the wires short to be "neat" (actually, to take the copper scrap home).  If they left you plenty of length, well that cut wire ain't returnable sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are excellent that you will only find a **listed** interlock kit for one inlet breaker position for your panel.

If you can find another, then you can do what you want. But as a rule, the maker produces one and only one interlock to fit each panel, if they produce one at all. And that kit requires a specific physical relationship for the inlet breaker relative to the main breaker.

Unclear why moving two breakers to make room in the correct spot (which is all you have to move) becomes "moving a lot of things" in your mind.

Comment: Let's say I swap the top 2 spots on both sides, am I right in thinking I shouldn't run the wires across the top where the supply lines come in?  So I have to go down all the way around the bottom and move the neutrals and grounds as well?  So I'd be extending 6 wires all the way around the other side or am I missing an easier alternative?

Comment: The breakers are not AFCI nor GFCI, so you don't need to touch the neutrals and grounds, and there's no rule against going across the top (other than respect the heck out of the connections that are always live, and pick up a set of the correct **Service Entrance Barriers** for the exposed connections, if your installation predates those being required.) Or wire-nut on a hunk of wire and go around the bottom if you prefer.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I think I will go the wire nut and around the bottom option.  Good to know that I don't have to find and move the neutrals and grounds.

Comment: Hey this covered most of what my answer did and was posted a bit sooner (crossed in writing). Where's the love, folks? +1